# The intersection of two ideals in $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_9]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_9]$ be a polynomial ring generated by $x_1,\ldots, x_9$. Let $$I_1=(x_1 -  x_2, x_1 -  x_3, x_5 -  x_6, - x_4 + x_5, - x_7 + x_9, - x_8 + x_9)$$ and $$I_2=(x_1 -  x_4, x_1 -  x_7, - x_2 + x_5, x_5 -  x_8, - x_3 + x_9, - x_6 + x_9).$$

I want to compute the intersection of the ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$. My computation is in the following.

The ideal $I_1 \cap I_2$ contains $$x_5 -  x_6 -  x_8 + x_9, \\
x_4 -  x_6 -  x_7 +x_9, \\
x_2 -  x_3 -  x_8 + x_9, \\
x_1 -  x_3 -  x_7+ x_9.
$$
$I_1 \cap I_2$ also contains the products of the generators of $I_1, I_2$. Using 
$$x_5 -  x_6 -  x_8 + x_9, \\
x_4 -  x_6 -  x_7 +x_9, \\
x_2 -  x_3 -  x_8 + x_9, \\
x_1 -  x_3 -  x_7+ x_9,
$$
we can remove some products of the generators of $I_1, I_2$. Then we know that 
$$
\{x_5 -  x_6 -  x_8 + x_9, \\
x_4 -  x_6 -  x_7 +x_9, \\
x_2 -  x_3 -  x_8 + x_9, \\
x_1 -  x_3 -  x_7+ x_9, \\
(x_6 -x_9)(x_8 -  x_9),\\
(x_3 -x_9)(x_8 -  x_9), \\
(x_6 -x_9)(x_7 -  x_9), \\
(x_3 -x_9)(x_7 -  x_9) \}
$$
is a subset of $I_1 \cap I_2$. How to check that whether this set is enough to generate $I_1 \cap I_2$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Aww hell no $\space$

Comment: Why not use Gröbner bases?

Comment: Each ideal defines a $3$-plane. Choose bases for them. The intersection of ideals is the ideal of the union of the planes, which is easy to write in that basis (it’s a monomial ideal in those coordinates). Then change coordinates back.